# Handling individual form validation errors in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to check for Form validation error for an individual element in codeigniter ?

I need to set 'has-error' class to the elements which failed the validation.
This is not about printing validation errors.

This is what I currently have :

```
<div class="form-group <?php /**if validation error for this element then*/ echo 'has-error'; ?>">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <div class="validation-error">
        <?php echo form_error ( 'name' ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control validate" name="name" placeholder="Your full name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try like below

```
<div class="form-group <?php  echo form_error('name') ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<div class="validation-error">
    <?php echo form_error ( 'name' ); ?>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control validate" name="name" placeholder="Your full name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `form_error` method will be empty, if there is no error on that field. So you have to check like this:

```
<div class="form-group <?php echo form_error('name') !== '' ? 'has-error' : '' ?>">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <div class="validation-error">
        <?php echo form_error ( 'name' ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control validate" name="name" placeholder="Your full name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need for `!== ''` or to compare `form_error('name')` to anything else.  Just test for its existence using `<?php  echo form_error('name') ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>`  You also forgot the semicolon, which may or may not be a matter of preference.

Comment: True, it returns empty string, so its okay not to check against. But you dont need the semicolon, since the ?> close the line. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: Which is exactly why I said it may or may not be a matter of preference.